# How to configure nginx + ssl with an encrypted key in .pem format

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

I would like to set up ssl for an existing nginx server.
I got handed both a certificate and the corresponding (encrypted) private key. Both are in .pem format (each in its own file).

About all tutorials (e.g. [1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins)) I found assume a key in the .key format.

When I configure + start nginx the certificate seems to get accepted so far. However I'm asked for a PEM pass phrase for the private key file.

Am I correct in the assumption that my only options are to either set up a nginx "ssl_password_file" with the pass phrase or use openssl/libressl to convert the .pem file containing the encrypted key to an unencrypted .key file like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979171/how-to-convert-pem-into-key)?

How else should I handle an encrypted private key in .pem format?

Answer (score 24):

You've pretty much answered your own question.

Don't be confused by file extensions. The private key, whether password protected or not, is usually in PEM format. Often `.pem` is used for the certificate file, so `.key` is chosen for the corresponding private key. But the file extension is irrelevant.

So you have three options:

- Manually boot the server and provide the password at the console. This is probably the most secure option but also impractical for many situations.
- Provide a password file using `ssl_password_file`
- Permanently remove the password protection using `openssl`

For example, to remove the password from a private key:

```
openssl rsa -in original.key -out plain.key
```

Comment: This just saved me a ton. Thank you kind internet stranger.